# Android WebView doesn't show unity builded web pages properly

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, android-webview, unity-webgl

I have developed an application in unity then I export it to WebGl then I have created a web page. When I preview the page on Android's Chrome browser there is no any problem, It shows the page in high quality however when I open the page in android WebView quality of graphics dramatically decreases. I have tested the same application on Android 7,8 and 9 but there is no difference between versions. I have tried `hardwareAccelerated` but the problem is already present. Is it possible to get same quality in WebView like it is in Chrome?

Answer (score 0):

You can give a try to [Chrome custom tabs](https://blog.mindorks.com/android-browser-lets-launch-chrome-custom-tabs-with-kotlin). They are far more performant than a webview and they give to users a seamless in-app user experience. 
Unfortunately webview lacks a lot of features of the common browsers and it's not the best choice to display complex web pages.